# Solution of Ordinary Differential Equation(ODE) using Integrating Factor(I.F.)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

Q) If $x(t)$ is a solution of

$(1-t^{2})\;dx - tx\;dt = dt$

and $x(0)=1$, then $x\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )$ is equal to

(A) $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left ( \frac{\pi }{6}+1 \right )$

(B) $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left ( \frac{\pi }{6}-1 \right )$

(C) $\frac{\pi }{3\sqrt{3}}$

(D) $\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{3}}$

**My Approach :-**   Here, ordinary differential equation(ODE) is :-

$(1-t^{2})\;dx - tx\;dt = dt$

Divide the whole equation by $dt$

$(1-t^{2})\;\frac{dx}{dt} - tx = 1$

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1+tx}{1-t^{2}}$

$\frac{dx}{dt} +\; \left ( \frac{t}{t^{2}-1} \right )x= \frac{1}{1-t^{2}}$

Now, Integrating Factor (I.F.) will be $e^{\int \frac{t}{(t^{2}-1)}\;dt}$. Now,substituting $t^{2}-1 = z$.It will become $e^{\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{z}\;dz} = \sqrt{z} = \sqrt{t^{2}-1}$.

Now, Solution of given ODE will be :-

$x\sqrt{t^{2}-1} = -\int \left ( \frac{1}{t^{2}-1} \right )\times \sqrt{t^{2}-1}\;dt + c$.

$x\sqrt{t^{2}-1} = -\int \left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{2}-1}} \right )\;dt + c$

$x\sqrt{t^{2}-1} = -ln|t+\sqrt{t^{2}-1}| + c$.

Now, using given condition $x(0)=1$

$1*i = -ln|i| + c$

Here, I am getting solution in terms of $’i’$ but it should be in in terms of $\pi$ and does not involve $'i'$. I am not getting where I am doing mistake. Please help.

Comment: When you integrate $1/z$ you get $\ln |z|.$  Keep the absolute value and things will work out.

Comment: Thank you @B. Goddard. If I consider integrating factor as $\sqrt{1- t^{2}}$ then I am getting answer as $A$ but my doubt is integrating factor will be $\sqrt{|t^{2}-1|}$. So, when $t^{2} < 1$ then I.F. will be $\sqrt{1- t^{2}}$. So,I should have to assume here $t^{2} < 1$. right ?

Comment: That should do it.